# How do angularJS modules work in multipage applications

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

If you have a webpage that uses one module across several pages, does that module need to be loaded every time a new page is opened or is it just loaded in the initial page (assuming there is no ng-routing in place)?

Comment: if every page is rendered from the server, then every page will be independent of every other page as far as angular is concerned.  Each page will be a new `ng-app`, with all new directives, controllers, services, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as JavaScript is concerned, a page is like Las Vegas: whatever JavaScript code was loaded an ran on the previous page, stays on that page.

When moving from page A to page B, the JavaScript code will be run again; in particular, an Angular application will get bootstrapped again, which implies reloading your module.

It really boils down to how JavaScript runs, it's not Angular-specific.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helped a lot.  Thanks.